# How to get Visual Studio to copy dependencies to a custom output folder?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, .net-5

I'm having some trouble with a .NET 5 project.  I have a core program, and a bunch of plugins. Up until now I was building everything, then rewriting the core program to change its static dependency on different plugins as needed. Complexity has now reached the point where I want to stop doing that, so I've rewritten a couple parts to load plugins dynamically at runtime.

I changed the build output folder in all the projects so everything will output to the same folder, so when I run a build, everything should all be there, available as needed. But when I try to load a plugin assembly, it fails at loading that plugin's dependencies.

When I was building everything to its own folder and setting up all the dependencies statically, this wasn't a problem. Everything that was needed got copied to the output folder. But now, that's not happening.  What do I need to do to get the plugins' dependencies copied to the output folder?